# Macbook Pro 2012 keyboard is typing weird symbols instead of letters and numbers

Tags: macbook-pro

I have an Macbook Pro 2012.

I can't log in and change it because there are some weird symbols showing when I type my password. The numbers and letters keys show some sign so I can not change it from the dash board. I found out it was this weird symbol issue when I pressed command and r and opened Safari. I tried to reset nvram but either I don't know how to do it or it does not work.

Comment: Try an external keyboard, your internal one may be damaged.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. If an external keyboard doesn't solve your issue, or you don't have an external keyboard, you may try selecting a different input method at the login screen: click the Input menu in the upper-right corner of the menu bar and choose the correct keyboard and language.

Comment: @Yeet Coconut What sign are you talking about? When you type your password, the characters do not appear in clear, but are replaced by an * in general. Is that the case? If so, this is normal. You must type your password then validate.

Comment: @Jean_JD when I type in my password and press enter , enter will also be a symbol thats when I turned off my mac and then pressed command + r and went to safari and typed my password and found out why I cant log in

Comment: Ok. If you can't do Reset SMC and/or Reset NVRAM, you can open the Mac and unplug the battery connector step 3 of this link : https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/MacBook+Pro+13-Inch+Unibody+Mid+2012+Battery+Replacement/10365  You wait 5 minuts and replug the battery. Verify that the battery did not swell causing keyboard issues.

Comment: @Jean_JD ok thank you ill let you know if it works

Comment: @TomGewecke I already tried that but it still shows the werid keys

Comment: @Jean_JD will it damage anything

Comment: If you're careful, no worries. You must of course disconnect everything electrically before and touch a metal part to evacuate the static electricity before carrying out the manipulations and especially not to force and use a hard plastic object like used credit card or other to disconnect the internal connector of the battery.

Comment: @Jean_JD I've got bad news , I searched around my whole house and not one screw driver fit in the mac books screws.